# translate docker run command (tensorflow-serving) into docker-compose

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Here is the docker run command:

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 \
--name tfserving_classifier \
-e MODEL_NAME=img_classifier \
-t tensorflow/serving
```

Here is what I tried but I am not able to get the MODEL_NAME to work

```
  tensorflow-servings:
    container_name: tfserving_classifier
    ports:
      - 8501:8501
    command:
      - -e MODEL_NAME=img_classifier
      - -t tensorflow/serving
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  tensorflow-servings:
    container_name: tfserving_classifier
    image: tensorflow/serving
    environment:
      - MODEL_NAME=img_classifier
    ports:
      - 8501:8501
```